# Calculate the average value of 5 star rating by grouping a unique id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose, mongodb-query

I am trying to calculate the average 5 star rating that i have passed to the database when a user clicks on any number of stars.

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const ratingSchema = mongoose.Schema({
    userId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'User'
    },
    productId: {
        type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Product'
    },
    noOfStars: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    }

},{timestamp: true})

const Rating = mongoose.model('Rating', ratingSchema);

module.exports = {Rating}
```

This is the model that i have created to send Ratings for a particular product. When the user clicks on a star the star value,producID and the userID is inserted into the database.

```
import React,{useEffect,useState} from 'react';

const aggregate = require("../models/rating").Rating.aggregate;
const{Rating}=require('../models/rating');

exports.RatingAdd=(req,res) =>{
    aggregate(
        [
            {
                $group:
                    {
                        _id: "$productId"


                    }
            }
        ]
    )
}
```

This is the controller i have created to retrieve the average star value of a particular product and show it in the front end. I don't understand how to get the count of the same product ids and then divide the total number of stars value by the product id count. I am unable to get the correct average value per product. How should i edit my code to bring out the average star value of each product and pass the average star value and the product id to my front end?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
db.products.aggregate({$group:{_id:'$productId',count:{$sum:1},avg:{$avg:'$noOfStars'}}},{$project:{_id:1,count:1,avg:{$round:['$avg',1]}}})
```

Is this what you need?

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec40ff1ce367b3630df8f13"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "C",
    "rating" : 1
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec40ff3ce367b3630df8f14"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "C",
    "rating" : 2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec40ff5ce367b3630df8f15"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "C",
    "rating" : 3
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec40ff6ce367b3630df8f16"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "C",
    "rating" : 4
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec40ffdce367b3630df8f17"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "A",
    "rating" : 4
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec40ffece367b3630df8f18"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "A",
    "rating" : 5
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec41001ce367b3630df8f19"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "A",
    "rating" : 4.5
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec41003ce367b3630df8f1a"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "A",
    "rating" : 4.2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec41009ce367b3630df8f1b"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "B",
    "rating" : 3.2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec4100bce367b3630df8f1c"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "B",
    "rating" : 2.2
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5ec4100ece367b3630df8f1d"),
    "userId" : "A",
    "productId" : "B",
    "rating" : 1.2
}
```

Result:

```
{ "_id" : "C", "count" : 4, "avg" : 2.5 }
{ "_id" : "A", "count" : 4, "avg" : 4.4 }
{ "_id" : "B", "count" : 3, "avg" : 2.2 }
```

Edited test data and include $round.

Comment: Yes this is what i am looking for , thank you , next question i have is how can i convert the average to a value less than 5, since i only have 5 stars in my front end , i won't be able to showcase the average value

Comment: if your noOfStars inside mongoDB are all less than 5. Calling $avg will definitely get less than 5.

Comment: I edited the test data I used ... I have included a round up to the nearest 1 decimal if you need it. If you are worried if there are more than 5 inside your noOfStars, just do a $match before the $group, though that defeat the purpose of the rating system, since you should have validation for that before inserting into the DB.